# ¿Cómo obtener el último ID insertado en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy trabajando en Backpack y ocupo guardar una variable que termine con el número del último ID.

He intento lo siguiente en el método *store* de mi CRUD Controller, en la variable *$last* quiero guardar el valor del ID del último  registro.

He visto los métodos de *last()* y *lastInsertId()* pero no sé cómo implementarlos en mi solución.

```
<?php
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{

    $rfc = ...
    $cli_rfc = ...
    $date = ...

    $last = Object::all()->lastInsertId();

    $request->ultimo_numero =
        $rfc.'-'.
        $cli_rfc.'-'.
        $date. '/'.
        $last->id+1;
    $request->request->set('ultimo_numero',$request->ultimo_numero);
    // your additional operations before save here
    $redirect_location = parent::storeCrud($request);
    // your additional operations after save here
    // use $this->data['entry'] or $this->crud->entry
    return $redirect_location;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No conozco de backpack, pero con Eloquent puedes obtener el registro más reciente e igualar una variable con dicho valor de este modo:

```
$data = Modelo::latest('id')->first();
```

Pasa como argumento al método `latest()` la columna `id` para que sea por esta por la que ordene de forma descendente y de este modo obtengas el último registro realizado.

Le encadenas el método `first` para solo devolver el primer registro

Comment: Me devuelve el primer _id_ de la tabla

Comment: @NoobDev checa la edición que haré espero te ayude

Comment: lastInsertId does not exist. :(

Comment: no uso ese método @NoobDev, entonces por favor trata de aplicarlo como lo redacte pues lo acabo de probar en un ejemplo y funciona

Comment: Excelente, fue un error mío. Gracias, todo funcionando

Answer (score 2):

Backpack te ofrece el modelo nuevo generado mandando llamar a cualquiera de estas dos variables

```
$model = $this->data['entry'];
$model = $this->crud->entry;
```

En ambos casos solo apunta a id

```
$latest_id = $model->id;
```